# Run SQL script inside Docker with PostgreSQL and Spring

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker

Initially, the goal is to run the sql script when the volume is created to add the user to the database, but the problem is that the database runs before the spring service, so the script runs before the jpa initializes the necessary tables, and consequently an error occurs. What is the right way to solve this problem, should this script try to run inside the database volume or I had the idea to run it in ENTRYPOINT inside the spring Dockerfile after the jar file is run and the conditional 10 seconds have passed, but it didn't work either. I attach the docker-compose.yaml file below:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  db-postgres:
    image: "postgres:15.1"
    container_name: my-database
    volumes:
      - my-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  spring:
    build: ./my-service
    container_name: my-service
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - db-postgres
```

I am expect to find the right way to execute sql scripts when database is initialized by jpa

Comment: The Spring documentation has a chapter on [Database Initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization) that could be worth reviewing for generic techniques here.  These will work in any environment even if your application or database isn't running in Docker.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a Spring Boot application with JPA creating the database schema on the startup. In this case you can let JPA run your initialization script as well. You just need to put the script on the classpath and name it either schema.sql or data.sql.

In addition you must tell JPA to run the script only after the creation of the tables is done. Use this property:

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```